# OpenVZ has vzctl exec, what is the equivelent for lxc

Tags: openvz, lxc

I'm switching from OpenVZ to lxc.  The one thing that is really bugging me is that I can't find a lxc alternative to `vzctl exec`.  Before on OpenVZ I could do `vzctl exec 1033 restart nginx`. Now, all I can figure out to do is either run sshd in every container or use lxc-console, and I don't like either option (the first is too much management overhead, the second is too much of a hassle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`lxc-attach`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lxc-attach) instead? According the documentation,

> lxc-attach - start a process inside a running container.

Example to list all folders inside `home` of the container

```
lxc-attach -n myContainer -- ls -lh /home
```

If no process is defined, it creates a new shell inside the container.